# Copying .jpg file using shell script gives 'Failed to open input stream for file' error

Tags: bash, copy

Very simple script to copy a file

```
#!/bin/bash

#copy file
mtp-getfile "6" test2.jpg
```

I set it as executable and run it using

```
sudo sh ./test.sh
```

It gives me a file called test2.jpg that has no icon and I cannot open I get a 'Failed to open input stream for file' error

However, if I simply issue the following from the command line

```
mtp-getfile "6" test2.jpg
```

It works as expected. What is wrong with my script? I checked and the resulting .jpg file in each case has the same number of bytes. Very strange.

Comment: Your script may have DOS line endings, in which case you actually created a file named `test2.jpg\r` (that is, it contains a trailing carriage return).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was a permissions issue.
I only had to do a sudu chown test2.jpg

Answer (score 0):

As commented by chepner, your file might have a DOS (Windows) invisible line ending on its name, which would cause an error. To get rid of this unwanted character(s), just create a new blank script on your "nix" system and type the name by hand (not by copying and pasting, to avoid problems), let's say, name it test2.sh.

Then copy all the contents of test.sh to test2.sh (copy and paste) and run test2.sh and see if it works. If it doesn't, try running the following code on the new script, to make sure that there are no unwanted characters on the code itself:

```
tr -d "\r" < /folder/test2.sh && echo >> /folder/test2.sh
```

And then try to run script2.sh again to see if it works. Note: the `echo >> /folder/test2.sh` part of the code above is just to make sure that your new script ends with a newline, which is a Posix standard (and without which some programs may misbehave because they expect the file to end with a newline).